# LaunchScreen.xib leads to issue in view resizing

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, interface-builder, xib

I decided to replace LaunchImage by a LaunchScreen.xib, notably to reduce the number of assets - especially in a context with my app comes with numeral targets.

This works well BUT now I am using the LaunchScreen.xib, some views in my app are sized like on iPhone 5 while running on a iPhone 6/6s. Notably UIViewController containing a scrollView or tableView.

Not sure why. I could not figure out any reason. I remember having the same issue with the app behaving like on iPhone4 on a iPhone5 if I did not provide the appropriate LaunchImage assets, but the point of LaunchScreen.xib is not to have several right ?
Would appreciate if someone has some hints.

Answer (score 0):

In your project target general tab, select the LaunchScreen as your Launch Screen File.

[image]